# SQL Server - OPENROWSET Server name error using parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, openrowset

I'm having trouble with this query...Any idea how to declare variables and make it visible to OPENROWSET query?

```
  DECLARE @SERVERNM VARCHAR;

  SET @SERVERNM = (SELECT(CAST(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS VARCHAR) + '\' + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') AS VARCHAR)))

  SELECT 
      * 
  FROM
      OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','SERVER=@SERVERNM;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
  'set fmtonly off;exec DW..P750106119 @ENT_NR_VERSAO=1')
```

Error:

> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

Comment: Do you have that Trusted Connection set up on the server you're calling from? And does the User you're running this query as have permissions to access both?

Comment: You are declaring quite a few varchars here but NONE of them have the length specified. Don't rely on defaults, be specific. Do you know the default length can change based on how you use it? https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable within a literal string. In  your connection you're stating you want to connect to a server actually called `"@SERVERNM"`, **not** the value of `@SERVERNM`. Also, as you have `DECLARE @SERVERNM VARCHAR`, which is the same as `DECLARE @SERVERNM VARCHAR(1)`. I suspect this *might* work but ***assumes*** `@SERVERNM` will have a value of less than or equal to 128 characters:

```
DECLARE @SERVERNM sysname;
SELECT @SERVERNM = CAST(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS sysname)+'\'+CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') AS sysname);
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                ''SERVER=' + QUOTENAME(@SERVERNM,'"') + N';Trusted_Connection=yes;'',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                ''set fmtonly off;exec DW..P750106119 @ENT_NR_VERSAO=1'');'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: I changed a little bit your solution, but i got it !! cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

This is the declaration of the variables :

```
DECLARE @SERVERNM VARCHAR(100)

SET @SERVERNM = (SELECT(CAST(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS VARCHAR)+'\'+CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') AS VARCHAR)))
```

Comment: @ENT_NR_VERSAO is a variable inside Sp P750106119, so I don't need declare it, just set.

Comment: This won't solve the problem of `'SERVER=@SERVERNM;Trusted_Connection=yes;'`. Unlike some languages, T-SQL does not inline replace variable names within a literal string with the variables value. `DECLARE @var varchar(10) = 'abc'; SELECT '123@var';` won't return `'123abc'`, it'll return `'123@var'`. Plus the fact that you should be applying the logic of declaring your length not only to the variable declaration, but to the data types within the `CAST` expressions as well.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
DECLARE @SERVERNM sysname;
SET @SERVERNM = 'SERVER='+CAST(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS sysname)+'\'+CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') AS sysname)+';Trusted_Connection=yes;'
DECLARE @TEST NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TEST = QUOTENAME(@SERVERNM,'''')

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                ' + @TEST + ',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                ''set fmtonly off;exec DW..P750106119 @ENT_NR_VERSAO=1'');'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```